# Google Maps - Street View Static Image

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

Is there a way to insert an address into a link and have it bring up the street view?

For instance:

```
<img src="http://maps.google.com/?q=ADDRESSHERE&view=streetview" />
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Street View now has a static images API. Here's an example:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=640x480&location=43.0635309,141.3253261&fov=120&heading=235&pitch=10&sensor=false
```

Here's the docs:

https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/streetview/

2011:
[image: マクド]

2017:
[image: マクドナルド]

Answer (score 0):

You can embed whole the Street View on your page. Use googlemaps `GStreetviewPanorama` object for that. You can look at the example here:

http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/streetview/streetview_lazy.html

Comment: That's v2 code, which is deprecated.  Use the documentation and sample code at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#StreetView instead.

Answer (score 0):

Might be best to use Google Maps JavaScript API v3 to do it.  See documentation and sample code at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#StreetView.

Here's code from that page (with a few extraneous bits removed) that displays a street view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API Example: Embedded StreetView</title>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function initialize() {
    var bryantPark = new google.maps.LatLng(37.869260, -122.254811);
    var panoramaOptions = {
      position:bryantPark,
      pov: {
        heading: 165,
        pitch:0,
        zoom:1
      }
    };
    var myPano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"), panoramaOptions);
    myPano.setVisible(true);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="pano" style="width: 425px; height: 240px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that the code uses latitude and longitude rather than address.  If all you have is a street address, you can use Google's `Geocoder` object to convert an address to a `LatLng` object.