# Google StreetView Snapshot

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Google Maps for Android provide a method called [snapshot()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#snapshot(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback,%20android.graphics.Bitmap)) which allows the map to converted to a still image. I'm wondering is it possible to do the same for StreetView?

As far as I can see there is no method provided by Google for doing this so I'm wondering is it even possible to do this?

I tried converting the view to an image and had no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

THere are a few ways to do it. The first is to grab the image live and embed it:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/

The second is to pull down the pano by ID.
There are already apps developed for this, my favorite is Pano Fetch by Jaume Sanchez

If you're just after one or two panos, use mapcrunch or instantstreetview. http://www.mapcrunch.com/

Otherwise, use a business developer login. Be aware that there are charges for usage. You can download panos using the Streetview image API.

Comment: can i get snapshot by entering parameter to the first link for a specific location in android??kindly help me..

Comment: you doing well.i appreciate your effort, i have completely do this by getting help from your link here is my demo..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253268/google-maps-street-view-static-image/47667661#47667661