# How I can Take Snapshot of Street View in android programmatically?

Tags: android, google-maps, openstreetmap, google-streetview-publish

Getting snapshot from 2d map like satellite map  is easy , the method is provided and easy to use. I want to get snapshot from Live street view, from a specific location where panorama view is available. I am trying to do this by converting view to bitmap but no success. Kindly provide the code of snapshot if anyone know about this.

Comment: Anyway, you can use [static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/?csw=1) to get street view panorama image. Also, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7444539/6950238) answer of [nevan king](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74118/nevan-king)

Comment: oh yes thanks i got it,

Comment: here is my code link i done it in android successfully..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253268/google-maps-street-view-static-image/47667661#47667661