# Convert Google Streets URL to static image

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Google Street View has an api for static images, as referenced [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253268/google-maps-street-view-static-image).

Are the parameters needed for the static image located inside a Google Maps Street View URL? And is there a best way to extract it?

https://www.google.com/maps/@38.8803747,-77.0404946,3a,75y,71.74h,90.2t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1s5FO2Gol-VCDw3tTsT3iL7A!2e0!6shttps:%2F%2Fstreetviewpixels-pa.googleapis.com%2Fv1%2Fthumbnail%3Fpanoid%3D5FO2Gol-VCDw3tTsT3iL7A%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D355.97687%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i13312!8i6656

Like maybe the center 500px by 500px of the center of that URL's facing and zoom level?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to give you a complete answer but this is as close as I can get. The relevant parameters you need are all in the URL between the "6s" parameter and before the bangs (!) at the end. So I'll make two splits on the URL to get just that relevant portion. I'm assuming you'll never see a bang inside this portion of the URL since Google treats them as reserved characters:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/static-web-api-best-practices#special-characters

Next I'll decode the URL encoded characters and strip off the path because I want to use URLSearchParams to manipulate the URL from here (and it doesn't work with either):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams
https://www.sitepoint.com/get-url-parameters-with-javascript/

Then I'll get the params I need (panoid [as pano], h [as heading], pitch, and thumbfov [as fov]) and put them into my new URL. Note I haven't done anything with cb_client, w, or yaw because I don't think / know they translate to anything in a Street View request:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/overview#url-parameters

You'll need to change YOUR_KEY to be your actual Google Maps Platform API key. Also note that these requests aren't signed but you'll probably want to do that if you are making requests in bulk:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/get-api-key

```
//take the original URL as a
let a = "https://www.google.com/maps/@38.8803747,-77.0404946,3a,75y,71.74h,90.2t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1s5FO2Gol-VCDw3tTsT3iL7A!2e0!6shttps:%2F%2Fstreetviewpixels-pa.googleapis.com%2Fv1%2Fthumbnail%3Fpanoid%3D5FO2Gol-VCDw3tTsT3iL7A%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D355.97687%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i13312!8i6656";
//use string.split() twice to isolate the useful bits
let b = a.split("!6s");
let c = (b[1]).split("!");
//c[0] now contains the part we care about 
console.log("c[0] is " + c[0]);
//split off the query search parameters and url decode so we can use URLSearchParams
let d = (c[0]).split("%3F");
let e = (d[1]).replace(/%2F/g, "/").replace(/%3F/g, "?").replace(/%3D/g, "=").replace(/%26/g, "&");
console.log("e is " + e);
let params = new URLSearchParams(e);
//define the path for a Street View Static API request
let f = new URLSearchParams();
//grab parameters from the original url and insert them into the new url
if (params.get("panoid")) {
    let pano = params.get("panoid");
  f.append("pano", pano);
};
if (params.get("h")) {
    let heading = params.get("h");
  f.append("heading", heading);
};
if (params.get("pitch")) {
    let pitch = params.get("pitch");
  f.append("pitch", pitch);
};
if (params.get("thumbfov")) {
    let fov = params.get("thumbfov");
  f.append("fov", fov);
};
//write out the final url
let g = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?key=YOUR_KEY&size=500x500&";
console.log("the final URL is " + g + f.toString());
```